# WPF Datagrid SelectedIndex issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid to which I have added the DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged event to show RowDetails for that specific cell when clicked.
This is working all fine as it should, but now I have on some that the event fires once, but after that it won't trigger it anymore if I select a cell in the same row. I checked in DataGrid_SelectCellColumnChanged and it won't change the value of the SelectedIndex (dg.SelectedIndex), even so I force it to with static values. Can someone maybe explain that, or have an idea what causes that problem?

Here is some of the code:

Create datagrid:

```
public static DataGrid AddDataGrid(ViewInfo viewInfo, System.Data.DataSet ds, UIElement parent, bool isReadOnly, bool setHighlight = true, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler clickEvent = null, EventHandler<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs> editEndEvent = null, string tagName = "", bool addDataContext = true)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = null;
                ////Reconfigure the Column Types in the Table for Sorting later
                //if (DataGridExtension.CheckDataTableColumnTypeForDate(ds.Tables[0]))
                //{
                //    dt = DataGridExtension.ReConfigureDataTableColumnType(ds.Tables[0]);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    dt = ds.Tables[0];
                //}

                dt = ds.Tables[0];

                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid
                {
                    Name = "DataGrid__" + viewInfo.SprocName,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Margin = (tagName == "SubGrid") ? new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 10) : new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    AutoGenerateColumns = true,
                    Style = TriggerStyleUtility.CreateStyle<DataGrid>(DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightGray),
                    AlternationCount = 2,
                    IsReadOnly = isReadOnly,                    
                    CanUserAddRows = false,
                    CanUserDeleteRows = false,
                    Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                };

                dg.CellStyle = TriggerStyleUtility.CreateStyle<DataGridCell>(DataGridCell.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(10), dg.CellStyle);
                Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
                st.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(10)));
                //dg.CellStyle = st;


                //set events
                dg.AutoGeneratingColumn += DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn; 
                dg.Loaded += DataGrid_Loaded;

                if (clickEvent != null) dg.MouseDoubleClick += clickEvent;
                if (editEndEvent != null) dg.CellEditEnding += editEndEvent;

                dg.Sorting += DataGrid_Sorting;
                           

                //ColumnCount = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
                ColumnCount = dt.Columns.Count;

                List<object> list = new List<object>
                {                    
                    viewInfo
                };

                if (addDataContext) list.InsertRange(0, new List<object>() { ds } );

                dg.DataContext = list;
                //dg.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

                UIElementExtensions.SetHighlight(dg, setHighlight);

                //use this to evaluate if it is a SubGrid when Autogenerating Columns for ValueConverter
                dg.Tag = tagName;

                if (tagName == "SubGrid")
                {
                    dg.MaxHeight = 600d;
                    dg.SelectedCellsChanged += SubDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;
                }

                //set event for Cell selection changed (triggers when selected row changes)
                if (viewInfo.AddPNummerClick) dg.SelectedCellsChanged += DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;

                //enable and set RowDetails, and events
                //if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && viewInfo.AddRowDetails)
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && viewInfo.AddRowDetails)
                {
                    //set event for Cell selection changed (triggers when selected row changes)
                    if (!viewInfo.AddPNummerClick) dg.SelectedCellsChanged += DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;
                    
                    //add event when cell is clicked (triggers on each cell)
                    st = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
                    st.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DataGridCell.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(DataGrid_SelectCellColumnChanged)));
                    dg.CellStyle = st;

                    //add event for select row changes (used to bring focus to SubGrid)
                    st = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
                    st.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DataGridRow.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(DataGrid_SelectRowDetails)));
                    dg.RowStyle = st;

                    //create default Template for RowDetails
                    DataGridExtension.CreateRowDetailsTemplate(dg);
                }                

                //if no data set dummy item for NoDataTrigger
                //if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    dg.ItemsSource = new List<int> { -1 };
                    dg.Tag = "empty";
                    DataGridExtension.AddDataTemplate(dg, "Keine Daten gefunden!");
                    DataGridExtension.SetNoDataTrigger(dg);
                }
                               
                //check parent and set appropriate position for DataGrid
                if (parent.GetType() == typeof(DockPanel))
                {
                    DockPanel.SetDock(dg, Dock.Top);
                }
                else
                {
                    Grid.SetRow(dg, 1);
                }

                //add DatGrid to parent, so Highlights and DataGrid types can be processed (UpdateLayout)
                ControlUtility.AddUIElement(parent, dg);

                //highlight cells in DataGrid by max and lowest value in column
                if (setHighlight) DataGridExtension.StartCellHighlight(dg, viewInfo);

                //disable specific grid items (column, row, cell)
                if (viewInfo.DisableTableItems != "") DataGridExtension.DisableGridElements(dg, viewInfo);
                
                return dg;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FileLogger.HandleError("", false, true, "Error (DataGridUtility, AddDataGrid): " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, App._LogFilePath, App._LogFileName);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Code for DataGrid_SelectCellColumnChanged:

```
public static void DataGrid_SelectCellColumnChanged(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataGridCell dc = (DataGridCell)sender;
                DataGrid dg = ControlUtility.FindParent<DataGrid>(dc);
                UIElementExtensions.SetCurrentColumnIndex(dg, dc.Column.DisplayIndex);

                if (dc.Column.DisplayIndex == 0) return;               

                int col = UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg);
                int row = UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentRowIndex(dg);

                //change SelectedIndex to current Item Row, needed to trigger the cell changed event
                if (dg.SelectedIndex == -1 || UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg) == dg.SelectedIndex || (UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg) != dg.SelectedIndex && UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg) != 0))
                {
                    var currentRowIndex = dg.Items.IndexOf(dg.CurrentItem);

                    bool changed = (UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg) != dg.SelectedIndex && UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg) != 0) ? true : false;

                    //if current RowIndex is different, set SelectedIndex to current row
                    //otherwise reset to -1 and back to current RowIndex, so cell change event can trigger
                    if (currentRowIndex != -1 && UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg) != dg.SelectedIndex && !changed)
                    {
                        dg.SelectedIndex = currentRowIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (currentRowIndex == 0) return;

                        int test  = UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg);

// here it triggers normally the DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged event, which usually works
                        dg.SelectedIndex = col; // UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg);

/* trying to force it, but when debugging the SelectedIndex stays the same even after trying to set it static now,
and SelectedIndex has different value as test. It doesn't take the value?????   */
                        if (dg.SelectedIndex != test) dg.SelectedIndex = 5;
                        
                        App._CurrentColumnIndex = dg.SelectedIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FileLogger.HandleError("", false, true, "Error (DataGridUtility, DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged): " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, App._LogFilePath, App._LogFileName);
            }
        }
```

Class UIElementExtensions:

```
public class UIElementExtensions
    {
        //add Property "CurrentColumnIndex" and "CurrentRowIndex" to called UIElement
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentColumnIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentColumnIndex", typeof(int), typeof(UIElementExtensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static int GetCurrentColumnIndex(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            return (int)element.GetValue(CurrentColumnIndexProperty);
        }
        public static void SetCurrentColumnIndex(UIElement element, int value)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            element.SetValue(CurrentColumnIndexProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentRowIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentRowIndex", typeof(int), typeof(UIElementExtensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static int GetCurrentRowIndex(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            return (int)element.GetValue(CurrentRowIndexProperty);
        }
        public static void SetCurrentRowIndex(UIElement element, int value)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            element.SetValue(CurrentRowIndexProperty, value);
        }

        //add Property "Highlight" to called UIElement
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Highlight", typeof(bool), typeof(UIElementExtensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static bool GetHighlight(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            return (bool)element.GetValue(HighlightProperty);
        }
        public static void SetHighlight(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            element.SetValue(HighlightProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Code DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged:

```
public static void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;

        if (dg.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)(dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dg.SelectedItem));
        //return if no row found (happens when sorting by column)
        if (row == null) return;

        // Getting the ContentPresenter of the row details
        DataGridDetailsPresenter presenter = ControlUtility.FindVisualChild<DataGridDetailsPresenter>(row);
        Grid parent = ControlUtility.FindVisualChild<Grid>(presenter);

        //update presenter Layout to get Grid if presenter is still null
        if (parent == null)
        {
            presenter.UpdateLayout();
            parent = ControlUtility.FindVisualChild<Grid>(presenter);
        }

        DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dg.SelectedItem;
        
        //do stuff
        
    }
}
```

Edit: To make this a little more clear, this normally works as it should, only on some loaded sprocs it doesn't work. I changed the sprocs on which it doesn't work with code from where it works, but the problem consists, so that can't be the issue. Also if I click another cell in another row, than it works again, but again only for one time. On other sprocs it always works.
Also how can a field (public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }) not be forced to take a value? That's what irritates me the most on it.

FYI: the problem is in the DataGrid_SelectCellColumnChanged event. When SelectedIndex is changed here. This normally triggers the DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged, when it works.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you set `SelectionUnit="Cell"` by the `DataGrid`?

Comment: If I add that, I get an error after the first selektion saying: "{"No rows are selected due to the current value of the SelectionUnit property for the parent DataGrid."}", and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Due to this being selectionchanged driven you might have debugging complications. If you put a debug.writeline in your two changed event handlers. Right at the top. Do they actually still output to console even when not "working"?  I have another question as well but posters often ignore most if you ask more than one.

Comment: Yes, it even gets the new clicked index and displays the value (UIElementExtensions.GetCurrentColumnIndex(dg)), but it won't apply it to SelectedIndex, which is very irritating. Well the second one won't trigger, because SelectedIndex doesn't change it's value. But yes all works in regards to that.